# Getting System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified error when taking ownership of files

Tags: c#

In in the process of making an application that gets executed as an Administrator user. The application copies and overwrites files if the said file exists to certain locations on C:\, If the Administrator does not have access  to perform the operation on the requested file then the application will take ownership and assign full control permission to the administrator user so that they can overwrite the said file.

however I am getting the following error when it tries to do this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'
```

I have been reading that Foreach loops can't be modified during the iteration process.  So I converted my code to use a For loop but the issue still persists! I've spent many hours trying to get this to work and research but I have ended up going in circles, any help would be appreciated.  Below is my code:

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp2\BarsInstaller\FilesToInstall.txt");
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Temp2\BarsInstaller\";

            for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length; i++)
            {


                string[] col = lines[i].Split('=');
                string fileName = col[0];
                string pathName = col[1];


                string fullDestPath = pathName + fileName;
                string fileCopyToLocation = pathName;
                string fulleSourcePath = sourcePath + fileName;



                copyFilesToInstall(fulleSourcePath, fullDestPath, fileCopyToLocation);

}

void copyFilesToInstall(string sourceFile, string destFile, string target)

        {
            if (Directory.Exists(target) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
            }

            //1 check if we have permissions to overrite the file or copy file to directory
            //if we dont then give us permisison

            string fileName = destFile;

            Console.WriteLine("Adding access control entry for "
                + fileName);


            // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the
            // current security settings.
 if (File.Exists(destFile))
{
                FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(destFile);

  // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
 fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User,
FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
fSecurity.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User);

 using (new ProcessPrivileges.PrivilegeEnabler(Process.GetCurrentProcess(), Privilege.TakeOwnership))
                {
                    fSecurity.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
                }


                // Set the new access settings.
                File.SetAccessControl(destFile, fSecurity);         

}


}
```

Full Stack trace

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)\r\n   
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   
at ProcessPrivileges.PrivilegeEnabler.InternalDispose() 
in C:\\Users\\bazile\\source\\repos\\ProcessPrivileges\\src\\ProcessPrivileges.Shared\\PrivilegeEnabler.cs:line 191\r\n   
at ProcessPrivileges.PrivilegeEnabler.Dispose() in C:\\Users\\bazile\\source\\repos\\ProcessPrivileges\\src\\ProcessPrivileges.Shared\\PrivilegeEnabler.cs:line 149\r\n  
 at BarsInstaller.Form1.copyFilesToInstall(String sourceFile, String destFile, String target) in D:\\SourceControl\\BarsInstaller\\BarsInstaller\\Form1.cs:line 224
```

Comment: I can't see where this code would throw that exception.  I would recommend breaking on the exception and then adding details of the exact line of code that causes the throw

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown

Tick All CLR exceptions not just a specific one for ease

Comment: @AlanMacdonald exact line is 295  same line as closing brace which is straight after fSecurity.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User);

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs to support this but try adding fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(destFile); to reload the object after the first call to fSecurity.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User); but before the second within the using block.  The only logical thing to me based on the error is because SetOwner was already called it modified something so to do it again you need the file security object to be refreshed

Comment: Hi @AlanMacdonald  Tried what you mentioned and still getting the same error message :(

Comment: If you can share the full stack trace of the exception, maybe we can see where the error actually happens.

Comment: Hi @OguzOzgul Full Stack trace added to original question

Comment: As I suspected, problem is not with FileSecurity Class but with NTFS Security library, it is open source and I did not get this error with the latest version , need to check the source code of it now

Comment: Did you modify the source code of PriviligeEnabler? Anyway, please check line 191 of C:\\Users\\bazile\\source\\repos\\ProcessPrivileges\\src\\ProcessPrivileges.Shared\\PrivilegeEnabler.cs

Comment: @OguzOzgul I used Nuget Package manager to add ProcessPrivileges by Nick Lowe Version 1.5.7 so i don't have the source.

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved this with the help from @OguzOzgul the issue was that the Nuget Package I was using had a bug version 1.5.7 so I downloaded the source code from this site: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=processprivileges built it and added the DLL as a reference and this error is now gone.